# ROS-Gazebo Failed to load joint_state_controller

Tags: ros, microcontroller, gazebo, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'am following this tutorial about ROS Integration on Gazebo 1.9 (http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo).

My issue is:
As example I consider RRBot, when I type these commands:

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

to start simulation, and

```
roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch
```

to load controllers, it gives me these errors:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397731938.843439] [11.566000] Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1397731939.851478] [12.570000] Failed to load joint_state_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397731939.852413] [12.571000] Loading controller: joint1_position_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1397731940.860462] [13.576000] Failed to load joint1_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397731940.861270] [13.576000] Loading controller: joint2_position_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1397731941.869383] [14.581000] Failed to load joint2_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397731941.870228] [14.581000] Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1397731941.876315] [14.588000] Started controllers:
```

Then, if I type:
rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types
it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Service [/controller_manager/list_controller_types] is not available.
```

How can I resolve?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154166/ros-gazebo-failed-to-load-joint_state_controller/) by [Il_Voza](https://answers.ros.org/users/14661/il_voza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got the same problem and I've figured it out how to solve it.
You are having this problem cause you don't have installed the controllers.
Just run these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control ros-indigo-ros-controllers`
```

After that when you try to run the same commands you'll be able to control the arm of rrbot.

---

Originally posted by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) with karma: 110 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this message:

```
ERROR: Service [/controller_manager/list_controller_types] is not available.
```

you either don't have a running controller_manager, or it's not in the root namespace. What does this return?

```
rosservice list | grep controller_manager
```

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on 2018-03-20**:
Hello,

If the controller manager is running in the robot name space, what does it mean?

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2018-12-12**:
it either returns /controller_manager/load_controller or /<robot_name>/controller_manager/load_controller?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check if the joint names (joint1,joint2) in your .yaml file and your .urdf.xacro match.

---

Originally posted by [Dani C](https://answers.ros.org/users/12031/dani-c/) with karma: 126 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3